# Number of Classes in a Genus of a Quadratic Form?

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, quadratic-forms

I have been studying the representation of integers by sums of squares. Consider the equation
$$x_1^2+\cdots+x_n^2=k,$$
and let $r_n(k)$ denote the number of integer solutions. One way to compute $r_n(k)$ is to use the circle method of Hardy, Littlewood, and Ramanujan, which yields the asymptotic
$$r_n(k)=\frac{\pi^{\frac n2}k^{\frac n2-1}}{\Gamma\left(\frac n2\right)}\sum_{q=0}^\infty A_q+O\left(k^{\frac n4}\right),$$
where $\Gamma$ is the usual Gamma function,
$$A_q=q^{-n}\sum_{\substack{a\bmod q \\ (a, q)=1}}\left(\sum_{x=0}^{q-1} e\left(-\frac{ax^2}{q}\right)\right)e\left(-\frac{ak}{q}\right),$$
with $e(z)=e^{2\pi iz}$. This approach only works for $n\geq 3$, and the error term is known to be identically zero for $3\leq n\leq 8$. But for $n>8$, there are times when the error term is nonzero, and by looking at the Smith-Minkowski-Siegel mass formula, it seems that the obstruction is that the genus of the quadratic form $x_1^2+\cdots+x_n^2$ has more than one equivalence class for certain values of $n>8$.

Is this observation true? I would think that the genus of this particular form should contain precisely one class, namely $SO(n, \mathbb Z)$, yet the above observations suggest otherwise. It's not at all clear to me why this would even depend on $n$, especially since the condition that $n>8$ seems sort of random. When is the genus of $x_1^2+\cdots x_n^2$ bigger than just one class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Watson's project of finding all genera of class number one, positive forms, was automated by [Kirschmer and Lorch,](https://arxiv.org/abs/1208.5638).  The maximum dimension is 10.

Watson proved in his [1962 Transformations paper](http://zakuski.math.utsa.edu/%7Ekap/Watson_Transformations_1.pdf) that any genus of positive quadratic forms of dimension 11 or larger has class number larger than one.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for.